# New mobile chat interface broken on UC Browser HD for Android

Tags: bug, chat, mobile-web

The new mobile chat interface is very buggy on [UC Browser HD](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.uc.browser.hd) for Android. A minor problem is shown in the screenshot below:

[image: screenshot of the chat interface]

as you can see, the "search room" text is distorted. More importantly:

- I can't click click on the search bar to actually search for something.
- I can't scroll down or up, I only get one screenful of messages.
- I can't actually chat; there's no text box for chatting.
- Clicking on a message only selects it, the pop up menu with available actions that appears when using chrome is absent.

I tested this on a Samsung Galaxy Tab Pro 10.1 (SM-T520). On my phone, a Galaxy Express 2 (SM-G3815) the new interface doesn't even load (I'll be posting a separate bug report for that once I've made sure it's reproducible) so I can't check.

Comment: I'm not sure that browser is supported by SE. It also seems to seriously lag behind other browsers in supporting modern features, which could explain why the new chat is broken in this browser.

Comment: @MadScientist fair enough. I still think it's worth reporting though. What do you mean about its lagging behind? Like what?

Comment: [UC Browser is not supported for mobile view](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71208/241919), though it didn't explicitly say mobile chat. Previously, I remember there's a [tag:feature-request] to add UC Browser as supported browser, but it's been [meta-tag:status-declined] and possible roomba'd (since I couldn't find it)

Comment: Ah, OK. That might be a valid dupe target then.

Comment: Very unrelated, but [UC browser has serious privacy issues](https://citizenlab.org/2015/05/a-chatty-squirrel-privacy-and-security-issues-with-uc-browser/). I would stay away from it..